# Upgrading from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS Issues

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, dvd

I have a new laptop running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and noted the recent updates available so I have downloaded the image of 14.04 to a DVD disc and go through update manager.
This then ask me to insert the media:

"CD/DVD 'Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS *Trusty Tahr* - Beta amd64 (20150805)' is required

Please insert the above CD/DVD into the drive '/media/cdrom/' to install software packages from it."

The DVD I have created is in the drive and is called:

"Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS amd64"

Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you use to burn the iso to CD/DVD? Or did you use a pendrive?

Comment: Also, which ISO did you download?  (It looks like it's looking for a beta ISO, not a full 14.04.3 ISO)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for taking the time to reply. I have now successfully installed 14.04 LTS -but I have an issue.

I put my password in during the installation but now it is not recognised when we get to the initial sign in page and I have had to log in as a Guest User.

I am totally sure that the password I have entered during the installation of 14.04 LTS is correctly typed to what I am now currently entering - can anyone advise if this is a common issue and how it is resolved please?

Comment: Are you sure your keyboard was configured the same during the installation and now? (language + numeric + cap...)

Comment: I have now fully reinstalled 14.04 LTS and deselected the option asking about a password on starting and this now allows access :o) I am a convert from Windows and slowly finding my feet. Thank you again for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem.

Then, I found that in software and update center, there was Ubuntu Trusty Tar update given. I unchecked that and the installation of software was taking successfully place.

[image: error]

Comment: if you are not getting what i am saying ping me on fb my name is yash gaurkar.